# neo4j admin import Error in import Requested index -1, but length is 1000000

Tags: neo4j

I have a set of CSV's that I have been able to use with LOAD CSV to create a database. This set is the small version (1 gb) of a much larger data set (120 gb) I intend to load to neo4j using admin import. I am trying to run the admin import on the smaller dataset first since I have already successfully created a graph with that data. I assume that if I can get the admin import to run for the small version it will hopefully run without problems for the large dataset. I've read through the admin import instructions and I've set up header files. The import loads the nodes just fine but ends up failing with he relationship files. Can anyone help me understand what is happening here so that I can figure out how to fix it? I've tried just removing the file and its associated nodes but this only results in the same error being thrown from the next file in the relationships list.

```
   IMPORT FAILED in 9s 121ms. 
Data statistics is not available.
Peak memory usage: 1.015GiB
Error in input data
Caused by:ERROR in input
  data source: BufferedCharSeeker[source:/var/lib/neo4j/import/rel_cchg_dimcchg.csv, position:3861455, line:77614]
  in field: :START_ID(cchg-ID):1
  for header: [:START_ID(cchg-ID), :END_ID(dim_cchg-ID), :TYPE]
  raw field value: 106715432018-09-010.01.00.0
  original error: Requested index -1, but length is 1000000
org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.input.InputException: ERROR in input
  data source: BufferedCharSeeker[source:/var/lib/neo4j/import/rel_cchg_dimcchg.csv, position:3861455, line:77614]
  in field: :START_ID(cchg-ID):1
  for header: [:START_ID(cchg-ID), :END_ID(dim_cchg-ID), :TYPE]
  raw field value: 106715432018-09-010.01.00.0
  original error: Requested index -1, but length is 1000000
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.input.csv.CsvInputParser.next(CsvInputParser.java:234)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.input.csv.LazyCsvInputChunk.next(LazyCsvInputChunk.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.input.csv.CsvInputChunkProxy.next(CsvInputChunkProxy.java:75)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.ExhaustingEntityImporterRunnable.run(ExhaustingEntityImporterRunnable.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.neo4j.internal.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Requested index -1, but length is 1000000
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.cache.OffHeapRegularNumberArray.addressOf(OffHeapRegularNumberArray.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.cache.OffHeapLongArray.get(OffHeapLongArray.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.cache.DynamicLongArray.get(DynamicLongArray.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.dataValue(EncodingIdMapper.java:767)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.findFromEIdRange(EncodingIdMapper.java:802)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.binarySearch(EncodingIdMapper.java:750)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.binarySearch(EncodingIdMapper.java:305)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.get(EncodingIdMapper.java:205)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.RelationshipImporter.nodeId(RelationshipImporter.java:134)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.RelationshipImporter.startId(RelationshipImporter.java:109)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.input.InputEntityVisitor$Delegate.startId(InputEntityVisitor.java:228)
    at org.neo4j.internal.batchimport.input.csv.CsvInputParser.next(CsvInputParser.java:117)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually quite explicit: have a look at line 77614 in `rel_cchg_dimcchg.csv`. It's usually caused by an incorrect endpoint id. For example, if the END_ID is supposed to be a number but it's something like `4171;4172;4173;4174;4175;4176` this will raise the `InputException` error.

One would assume that `--skip-bad-relationships` would ignore these issues but it doesn't. So, the only remedy is to ensure that all START_ID/END_ID's are correct (ie. the right data type and format).